# where is exported file after export button pressed?

Tags: excel, sqlite

i have tried exporting function in my sqlite database to exporting it to excel sheet.but i don't know wheather my exporting function implemented sucessfully if yes,so where is my exported file and if my code contain some error kindly help me out becoz i am new to android.this is my sqlite controller class which is including export function:-

```
public class SQLController {

private DBhelper dbhelper;
private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    ourcontext = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new DBhelper(ourcontext);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void insertData(String name) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, name);
    database.insert(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, null, cv);
}

public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID,
            DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME };
    Cursor c = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public int updateData(long memberID, String memberName) {
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, memberName);
    int i = database.update(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, cvUpdate,
            DBhelper.MEMBER_ID + " = " + memberID, null);
    return i;
}

public void deleteData(long memberID) {
    database.delete(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, DBhelper.MEMBER_ID + "="
            + memberID, null);
}

public void export() throws IOException{
    File dbFile=ourcontext.getDatabasePath(dbhelper. DB_NAME);
  File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/XLS", "");
    if (!exportDir.exists())
           {
               Log.d("export", ""+exportDir);

               exportDir.mkdirs();

           }

           File file = new File(exportDir, "Your file.xls");

               file.createNewFile();
   File file8 = null;
   CSVWriter csvWrite8 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file8));
      String[] allColumns = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID,
        DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME };
       Cursor c = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, allColumns, null,
          null, null, null, null);


CSVWriter csvWrite = null;
if(c.moveToFirst())
               {
                   c.moveToFirst();

                   Log.d("log is","No of Column is ---->>>"+c.getColumnNames().length);

                  do 
                   {
                       String arrStr[] =         {c.getString(0),c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5)};

                       csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);


                   }while(c.moveToNext());
               }
               csvWrite.close();
 }


}// outer class end
```

this is my db helper class

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// TABLE INFORMATTION
    public static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "member";
    public static final String MEMBER_ID = "_id";
    public static final String MEMBER_NAME = "name";

    // DATABASE INFORMATION
    static final String DB_NAME = "MEMBER.DB";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

// TABLE CREATION STATEMENT
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
        + TABLE_MEMBER + "(" + MEMBER_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MEMBER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public DBhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

this is my class in which i am calling export function in button id case

```
public class Modify_member extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText et;
Button edit_bt, delete_bt,bt;

long member_id;

SQLController dbcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.modify_member);

    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_mem_id);
    edit_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_bt_id);
    delete_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_bt_id);
    bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ex);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String memberID = i.getStringExtra("memberID");
    String memberName = i.getStringExtra("memberName");

    member_id = Long.parseLong(memberID);

    et.setText(memberName);

    edit_bt.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_bt.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.update_bt_id:
        String memName_upd = et.getText().toString();
        dbcon.updateData(member_id, memName_upd);
        this.returnHome();
        break;

    case R.id.delete_bt_id:

        dbcon.deleteData(member_id);
        this.returnHome();
        break;
    case R.id.ex:

        try {
            dbcon.export();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.returnHome();
        break;

    }}
public void returnHome() {

    Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        f.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(home_intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates: the file folder is your "exportDir", and the file name is "Your file.xls".

Try to look for your files. But make sure the file is actually generated before then.